# Видео камера на сайт

Tags: flash, javascript

Наверняка в фильмах видели охранная камера двигается туда сюда. Вот на сайт сделать нужно камеру такую. Всё бы было просто, но хочется сделать, чтобы она поворачивалась за курсором. Куда мышку - туда и камера. Как такое можно реализовать? Если сайт не на флеш, можно ли сделать это на флеше? Или может знает кто-то способ проделать такое на js?

PS: Камера конечно же ничего снимать не должна))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хех.. Этим вопросом вы напомнили мне старые времена. )) Тогда подобную фишку реализовывали достаточно просто с помощью JS: виртуально разделяем видимую область на несколько частей и, в зависимости от того, над какой областью находиться курсор, показывалась соответствующая картинка (тогда это был глаз). Если курсор внизу экрана, то картинка, где глаз смотрит вниз, если вверху - то картинка, где глаз смотрит вверх и т.д.

Таким сегодня как бы не балуюсь, но если такой пример подойдет, то почему бы и нет? ))

Comment: Спасибо, хорошая реализация, только много кадров прийдётся сохранять, считай почти каждый пиксель обновлять картинку. И в последствии долго грузится будет.

Comment: @mctrane, да ну бросьте )) Сейчас такие срипты используются на сайтах, что такой будет просто "карликом" по сравнению с ними. Подгружать картинки каждый раз не нужно. Грузятся они вместе, а показывается только определенная.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы отслеживал положение мыши в viewport'e ([mouse position](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aMouse_Position#Tracking_mouse_position)), и в зависимости от того как релизуется камера ( набор картинок или одна универсальная или как-то ещё), применил бы математику и поворачивал/изменял её.